# SAS Get metadata capabilities from a Role

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide, sas-metadata

I have a role of my system, but i need a script for get the metadata capabilities of this role. I have the URI that identify my Role, but i dont know how i can get all capabilities.

thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `%MDUEXTR` macro function to extract identity information from metadata. The macro will write the metadata to a couple of  SAS tables (called [Canonical Tables](http://morgan.dartmouth.edu/Docs/sas92/support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/bisecag/61133/HTML/default/a003069101.htm)) which will contain user and group details [SAS Documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=bisecag&docsetTarget=n024i4nqa5b12qn1lfek77h69ns5.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en).